# How to disable the "Insecure Connection" while opening up a private browser from python selenium script?

Tags: python, linux, selenium, firefox

While running my python selenium  script for firefox browser; I encountered an issue saying

> Your connection is not secure

It is not allowing me to Add exception and blocked

> Confirm Security Exception

as well (even with preferences manually). hence i am trying to add profiles like "webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs", "webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs" but nothing is helping me out. Not sure how to tackle this...

I need some help here

Currently using the following...
Python 3.4.4
selenium==3.4.1
linux 32 bit
Firefox 60.6.1esr (32-bit)
Everything seems to be compatible, so no issue here.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import     DesiredCapabilities

cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer", False)
profile.update_preferences()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=cap,firefox_profile=profile)
browser.get('my url')
```

and

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import     DesiredCapabilities

cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs", True)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=cap,firefox_profile=profile)
browser.get('my url')
```

I want to get rid of the "Your Connection is not secure"

Comment: is `my url` using HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: it's using https

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247155/selenium-interacting-with-your-connection-is-not-private

Answer (score 4):

For FireFox you can use:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

desired_caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
desired_caps.update({'acceptInsecureCerts': True, 'acceptSslCerts': True})
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=self.desired_caps)
```

For Chrome:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: no working with ChromeDriverManager().install()

Comment: @myworldbox in order for us to help you please provide more details. How did you start your chrome instance?

Comment: The real solution should be don’t register a email with a common phone number and enable less security app to be executed.