# How to bypass the message-"your connection is not private" on non-secure page using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, connection

I'm trying to interact with the page "Your connection is not private".

The solution of using `options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')` is not helpful for two reasons:

1. I'm using an already open window.
2. Even if I was using a "selenium opened window" the script runs non stop, and the issue I'm trying to solve is when my browser disconnects from a splunk dashboard and I want it to automatically connect again(and it pops the private connection window).

How do I click on "Advanced" and then click on "Proceed to splunk_server (unsafe)?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**For chrome:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

If not work then this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost') # differ on driver version. can ignore. 
caps = options.to_capabilities()
caps["acceptInsecureCerts"] = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)
```

**For firefox:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get('https://cacert.org/')

driver.close()
```

If not work then this:

```
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get('https://cacert.org/')
driver.close()
```

Above all worked for me!

Comment: Do you happen to know a way to do this for Edge (Chromium)?

Comment: @schneida sorry, I didn't work with edge so can't tell. But I think as Edge use chromium engine so program for chrome browser should work.

Comment: I was thinking Edge would use the same parameters as chromium, but I tried it and that didn't work. I ended up using Selenium automation itself to click the continue button on the privacy page... Works fine

Comment: `edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions().merge(chromeOptions);driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);` something like this works.. you can try it.

Comment: the code for Chrome isn't valid python code

Comment: @rok Thanks for checking out. I am editing it.

Comment: options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i handle this problem:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;

ChromeOptions capability = new ChromeOptions();
capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS,true);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capability);
```

Answer (score 1):

This  chrome option is the silver bullet for me:

```
 chromeOptions.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
```

If you need more, Open chrome & paste this URL:

```
        chrome://flags/
```

One will find all the options and their impact on the chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Either of below 2 solutions worked for me using Python Chrome Selenium Webdriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
capabilities["acceptInsecureCerts"] = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

And accepted solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```