# How to enforce block-insecure-private-network-requests using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
chrome://flags/#block-insecure-private-network-requests
```

I want to Disable / Block insecure private network requests with selenium web driver chrome options Python.

What flag `add_argument()` do I need to add for that?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247155/how-to-bypass-the-message-your-connection-is-not-private-on-non-secure-page-us ?

Comment: `options.add_argument('--block-insecure-localhost')` also please try this

Comment: I try both options and both didn't work good for me.

I try also a combination between them

Answer (score 0):

As per the article [Private Network Access update](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-update/):

> August 25, 2021: Updated timeline announcement and introduction of a deprecation trial.

Chrome is deprecating access to private network endpoints from non-secure websites as part of the [*`Private Network Access`*](https://wicg.github.io/private-network-access/) specification. The aim is to protect users from cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attacks targeting routers and other devices on private networks. These [attacks have affected hundreds of thousands of users](https://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/22743/cyber-crime/soho-pharming-attack.html), allowing attackers to redirect them to malicious servers.

Chrome will introduce the following changes:

- Blocking requests to private networks from insecure public websites starting in Chrome 94.
- Introducing a deprecation trial which will end in Chrome 101. It will allow developers to request a time extension for chosen origins, which will not be affected during the deprecation trial.
- Introducing a Chrome policy which will allow managed Chrome deployments to bypass the deprecation permanently. Available in Chrome 92.

> PS:
>
> - If you need more time to mitigate the impact of the deprecation register for the deprecation trial.
> - If you have administrative control over your users, you can re-enable the feature using Chrome policies.

To mitigate the impact of the new restrictions, use one of the following strategies:

- [Upgrade your website to HTTPS, and if necessary the target server](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-update/#both-ends-https).
- [Upgrade your website to HTTPS and use WebTransport.](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-update/#web-transport).

---

### Conclusion

If you are using *Chrome v94.x* or above, it's already disabled by default.

Comment: I'm using Chrome v96.0.4664.45

When chrome is start the option that selected is default, no enable or disable.
So, what I try to do is to set it to disable from chrome is start.

Comment: I think on Chrome v94.x or above is enabled by default @DebanjanB

Comment: The fine print says _`Chrome is deprecating access to private network endpoints from non-secure websites`_

Comment: I know that, because of that I want to disable it with selenium